# What to try before power cycling unresponsive remote Windows Server VM

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I have some Server 2012r2 hosts (all remote QEMU/KVM virtual machines) that become unresponsive to new session requests: Can't RDP, `Enter-Pssession -ComputerName`, `Invoke-Command -ComputerName`, or even `Restart-Computer -ComputerName`.

Even their console is seemingly "frozen" with the the date and time of their demise.  Sending Ctrl-Alt-Del does nada.  "Restart" from the Virtual Machine Manager console, which is performed via ACPI or the QEMU agent electively, fail in both cases.

Interestingly enough most everything else continues to work: file sharing, DHCP/DNS services, NTDS (two are DCs), web services, SQL databases all keep right on working.  As such, it might be months before I have a reason to log into these systems only to discover I can't.

Also of note, services are accessible remotely using `SC`,services.msc,`Get-Service`, and the like.  Likewise `Get-Process` also works.  However `Get-WMIObject` and `Get-CimInstance` both do not making `Get-Process` considerably less useful for lack of the processes command syntax.

Stopping/Restarting services hasn't proven very successful: dependent services frequently hang.  This has been the case with restarting NETLOGON and stopping NTDS.

I found the suggestion to try Sysinternals `PSEXEC` exciting as I recalled it installs a temporary service on the target to execute commands.  Alas, the service installed, but it hung starting.

I have selected the `WINRS` suggestion as the answer even though I can't say (yet) that it works for me - sadly, I have already bounced all my hung servers.  But this *is* "one more thing to try before...".  Hopefully, more will be posted.

Comment: Then no, probably not. I've long wished that windows had a magic REISUB command. its been a while, I'm not even absolutely sure that modern linuxes support magic REISUB. you could try psexec, but I'm sure its a locked as your other interfaces

Comment: so can you connect to management for your services like your DBMS? if so, you could really mitigate the risks associated with powercycling if you can shutdown your application services that write, like your DBs gracefully. stuff like webservers or DHCP/DNS aren't really in a dynamic state, so they are unlikely to be harmed by an unexpected restart

Comment: well schucks. if you are using SQLServer, can you shut down services using SSMS? sometimes you just gotta do what you just gotta do. if you do have a DB backup schedule, you may want to try waiting until a backup has been performed, but yeah....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything will continue to work as long as it doesn't need to contact the specific Windows component that is hung. This sounds somewhat like any attempts to load/unload user profiles hang.

If you can use `sc.exe` or Get-Service, then use that to safely stop any "database" services that are running on the system (including mail servers and NTDS if possible) – or do the same through the database management tools. Afterwards, it becomes mostly safe to just pull the plug; the filesystem will recover.

Note that if the systems are set up for PSRemoting, then they're also set up for another protocol also carried over WinRM – you can use the `winrs` tool to directly run remote cmd.exe commands (somewhat like PSEXEC but relying on what's already there, not requiring any new services to be started).

It would be interesting to see if there is any difference between using 'winrs' with the `-nop` option ("no profile loading") and without that option. (PSRemoting likely hangs because it always loads the user's remote profile, but winrs can skip that.)

```
C:\>  winrs -r:db01.example.com -nop dir
C:\>  winrs -r:db01.example.com dir
```

It's unlikely that running `shutdown` in this way will be useful; it'll hang for the same reason as RPC-based remote shutdown does.

One method I've used to force a remote desktop to reboot when lacking any kind of console access was to remotely `taskkill` one of the "critical" processes such as Winlogon, which causes an immediate BSOD and an automatic reboot.

```
C:\>  winrs -r:db01 -nop tasklist
C:\>  winrs -r:db01 -nop taskkill /f /im winlogon.exe
C:\>  tasklist /s db01
C:\>  taskkill /s db01 /f /im winlogon.exe
```

Comment: Dang.  Now I'm sorry I bounced all of them.  "-nop" is very interesting.  I'll update the next time I have an opportunity to test winrs in this capacity (forty years doing this and I have never used it)!  But this is definitely "one more thing to try" before kicking the plug out so you get the answer.